# show that $\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i ^2\Big)^2\leq\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i \Big)\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i ^3\Big)$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let  $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n>0.$   How can I show that $$\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i ^2\Big)^2\leq\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i \Big)\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i ^3\Big).$$

Please provide me a hint to start.

Comment: Something like this screams "[Cauchy—Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)" or "[Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)" -- when you see an exercise like this, this should become one of your first thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\alpha_i^2=\alpha_i^{\frac{1}{2}}\alpha_i^{\frac{3}{2}}$, and then use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: All too easy.  +1